# How to check the bill of BigQuery ML that uses Vertex ai

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am software engineer who started using BigQuery ML.
To use BigQuery ML at my company, I checked the pricing of BigQuery ML. As it turns out, BitQuery ML has two types of bill. One is for simpler models, and the other is for complex models that I will use automatically take advantage of Vertex AI. Therefore, Google pricing pages says that they will charge based on the usage of Vertext AI with the amount of data processed in BigQuery.

My question is how I can check Vertex AI virtual machine or GCP that BigQuery ML used to train the ML model? This virtual machine and processing time is necessary to utilise the price calculator of Vertex AI. When it comes to processing time, I can check it in BigQuery console.

Question:
How can I check Vertex AI virtual machine or GCP that BigQuery ML used to train the ML model?

Answer (score 0):

For BigQueryML the pricing is calculated differently -- you don't pay for a VM usage or something like this.

There is more detail at the [BigQuery pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#bqml) but basically you have different considerations for each model type you use.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I also read the documentation and found that I am charged for "$5 per TB, plus Vertex AI training cost". To calculate the Vertex AI training cost, I think we need to know training time and its virtual machine. That's why I asked the question.  Here is a link of the calculator. https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator My question is how can I calculate the vertex ai training cost.  I apologise for confusion.

Comment: Actually, I could find a billing table in the BigQuery. Thank you.

Comment: @kojitanaka, could you post the name or query for the billing table?